# How to avoid exceeding the firestore quota while using React's live re-load?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, quota

I'm fairly new to react so I apologies if this is a basic question. I've tried looking on stack overflow, google, and Github for the errors, but didn't see many posts looking for the error or general terms around it - and none of the ones I found were helpful or directly relevant.

I'm using react with firebase's authentication and firestore services. I don't have any trouble working with the authentication service (in terms of reaching the daily limit), however, I've been reaching the firebase quota within the hour. This is the error I see:

`Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Quota exceeded.`

I'd like to know if it's the code that's causing these excessive reads, or if there could be another culprit like the react live re-load that fires off a read for every small change I make.

The app currently reads some data from a firestore collection and renders it to a page. Here's what the component looks like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from '../../lib/firebase';

import Navbar from '../Navbar';
import MainContainer from '../MainContainer';
import { PostView } from '../Post';

function Home({ currentUser }) {

  const [ posts, setPosts ] = useState([]);

  const signOutUser = () => firebase.auth().signOut();

  useEffect(() => {
    const userId = currentUser.uid;
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const postsRef = db.collection('posts');
    const query = postsRef.where('userId', '==', userId);
    async function getData() {
      const data = await query.get();
      setPosts(data.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    }
    getData();
  }, [posts, currentUser]);

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <MainContainer>
        <button onClick={signOutUser}>Sign out</button>
        {posts.length === 0 ? <h1>No posts to display</h1> : '' }
        <ul>
          {posts.map(post => (
            <li key={post.id}>
              <PostView post={post} />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </MainContainer>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

The above component is rendered in full at the root of the app (if the user isn't signed in, they get redirected to the login page).

In my understanding, the `useEffect` method loads the first time the component is mounted, and every time either `posts` or `currentUser` changes.

I have a sneaking suspicion that I'm doing something silly, causing a large amount of data reads and resulting in this error.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem I think was that I'm using a method that is meant for data fetching once. Even though I was using it in the `useEffect` function, I think I was badgering the firebase endpoint.

The solution (I think, I'm a react beginner) is to manage the firestore snapshot as [mentioned in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write).

I actually managed to get around it by using [react-firebase-hooks](https://github.com/csfrequency/react-firebase-hooks) which abstracts the data handling away.

I'd still love answers on how to do this appropriately from scratch in the `useEffect` API.